# Don't know how to solve inequality $x^4-2x^3+x^2 < 4$

Tags: inequality

Solve the inequality: $x^4-2x^3+x^2 < 4$

I'm simply not sure about how to go about solving this inequality - it looks rather different from what I'm used to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In effect this is the same as finding the real roots of $x^4-2x^3+x^2-4=0$.

Comment: Hint:  $x^4-2x^3+x^2-4=0$ has two rational roots and no other real roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin with factoring $x^2$ in the l.h.s.:
\begin{align}
x^2(x-1)^2<4&
\iff \bigl(x(x-1)-2\bigr)\bigl(x(x-1)+2\bigr)<0\iff(x^2-x-2)(x^2-x+2)<0\\
&\iff (x+1)(x-2)(x^2-x+2)<0,
\end{align}
the factorisation of $x^2-x-2$ being found with the *rational roots theorem*.

As the quadratic factor has no real root,it is positive, and the inequation is equivalent to
$$(x+1)(x-2)<0\iff -1<x<2.$$

Answer (score 6):

$$x^4-2x^3+x^2-4 < 0$$

$$(x-2)(x^3+x+2)<0$$

$$(x-2)(x+1)(x^2-x+2)<0$$

Notice that $x^2-x+2 > 0$, are you able to take it form here?

Answer (score 0):

Write as $x^4 - 2x^3 + x^2 - 4 < 0$. The only rational roots that $x^4 - 2x^3 + x^2 - 4$ can have are $\pm 1$, $\pm 2$, $\pm 4$. You can find that $x = -1$ and $x = 2$ are both roots and rewrite the equation as $(x + 1) (x - 2) (x^2 - x + 2) < 0$. The quadratic term $x^2 - x + 2$ has discriminant $-7$, so it's always positive and this inequality has the same solutions as $(x + 1) (x - 2) < 0$, namely $-1 < x < 2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** $x^4-2x^3+x^2=(x(x-1))^2$

**Hint 2:** $u^2\lt4$ is equivalent to $-2\lt u\lt2$.

Answer (score -1):

A strategy you can use in this case is:

- Make $y=x^2$
- Solve the inequality for $y$
- Go back to the $x$ variable for each inequality you found as solution for $y$

Comment: Could you explicit your answer a bit more... I can't really see why replacing $x^2$ by $y$ make the thing easier